# Create a Communication class that handles Java sockets for client/server

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking

Basically, as a learning task, I've asked to create a multiple client/server application. 
Within this, it is stated that I have to create a Communication class that is shipped with both the client and the server, within those classes I would create a Communication instance, where the client or the server would use methods "sendMessage" or "receiveMessage" to send/receive a Message object. 
 
The Client/Server should be blind to what method the communication class uses. I've attempted it below but I can't figure out how to call the methods from the Communication instance in my Client/Server?

I also believe it may be easier than I've done it with threads? If someone could give me the basic starting code or explain how to arrive at it I would be very grateful.
 Thanks!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket; 
import java.net.Socket;

public class Comms
{
boolean isServer;

public Comms(boolean isServer) throws IOException
{
    this.isServer = isServer;
    if (isServer == true)
    {   
        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(6000);
        try
        {
            while(true)
            {
                new ServerConnection(socket.accept());
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
        finally
        {
            socket.close();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        new ClientConnection(new Socket("localhost", 6000));
    }

}

class ServerConnection 
{
    private ObjectInputStream receive;
    private ObjectOutputStream send;

    private ServerConnection(Socket clientSocket) throws IOException
    {
        InputStream inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        receive = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
        OutputStream outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
        send = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
    }

    public void sendMessage(Message message) throws IOException
    {
        send.writeObject(message);
    }

    public Message receiveMessage() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        Message message = (Message) receive.readObject();
        return message;
    }

    public void closeServerConnection() throws IOException
    {
        receive.close();
        send.close();
    }
}

class ClientConnection
{
    private ObjectInputStream receive;
    private ObjectOutputStream send;

    private ClientConnection(Socket socket) throws IOException
    {
        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        receive = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        send = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
    }

    public void sendMessage(Message message) throws IOException
    {
        send.writeObject(message);
    }

    public Message receiveMessage() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        Message message = (Message) receive.readObject();
        return message;
    }

    public void closeClientConnection() throws IOException
    {
        receive.close();
        send.close();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: It is difficult to avoid using Threads (you can somewhat with the NIO classes). Also, search SO for the multiple postings about chat clients; everything you need to know has already been documented.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'm looking into creating the threads now, Will update code once it is complete.